# Как сделать чтоб можно по номеру строки выводить весь текст этой строки

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
ifstream question_1;//вопрос 1                  
{
question_1.open(question1);
if (!question_1.is_open())
{
    cout << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "файл открыт" << "\n\n" << endl;
    cout << text1 << endl;
    while (!question_1.eof())
    {
        
        //затирка для того чтоб последнее значение не повторялось
        text1 = "";
        // Объект откуда считывается, куда записывать
        getline(question_1, text1);//построчное считывание
```

Допустим у меня выпал номер 4 и соответственно мне нужно вывести весь текст 4 строки

Comment: Ну так читайте 4 строки и выводите последнюю считанную :) Даже не буду говорить, что так - `while (!question_1.eof())` - неправильно, потому что читать вам надо не до конца, а до нужной строки...

Comment: либо один раз прочитать файл, сделать индекс вида начало-длина. И тогда можно будет в один подход читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сначала считывать все строки из файла в массив строк. Тут есть два варианта, если вы изначально знаете количество строк, то просто создавайте массив этого размера. Предположим, что количество этих строк равно 5.

```
const int N = 5;
string* str_arr = new string[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    getline(question_1, str_arr[i]);
}
delete [] str_arr;
```

---

Либо же, если количество строк неизвестно воспользуйтесь контейнером `vector`.

```
vector<string> str_arr;
```

---

И при запросе номера строки выводить из этого массива элемент под индексом **[Номер запрошенной строки - 1]**.

```
int index;
cout << "Введите номер строки>";
cin >> index;
cout << str_arr[index - 1] << endl;
```

**UPD.** Добавил чтение по совету @KoVadim.

Comment: думаю, что само чтение также важно показать. Но если размер файла немного большой, то способ не очень

Comment: @KoVadim а какие улучшения или другие способы вы бы посоветовали?

Comment: Во первых, Вам не нужен массив. Ну совсем не нужен. Можно просто читать построчно и считать строки, при этом читать в одну и ту же строку. Нам же предыдущие строки не нужны.